# Python: loop through a list using all previous indexes with each index

Tags: python, algorithm, loops

Given a list `n` long, such as `['animal', 'dog', 'golden retriever']` or `['food', 'dinner', 'pasta', 'white sauce', 'fetucci alfredo']`, I need to loop through the array and get the current index, plus each previous index.

Is there any good way to loop through and do this such that a list of any length can still be turned into:

```
stuff['food']
stuff['food']['dinner']
stuff['food']['dinner']['pasta']
stuff['food']['dinner']['pasta']['white sauce']
stuff['food']['dinner']['pasta']['white sauce']['fetucci alfredo']
```

I'm moving increasingly deeper into an object, but each value may or may not yet exist, so I need to stop at each level down.  ie, `stuff['food']['dinner']` may exist, but I may still need to add pasta to dinner, white sauce to pasta, etc.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you want to associate data in a particular and rigidly hierarchical fashion? If so, just referencing the list elements in order might not be ideal; the dictionary datatype might be what you need. This would allow you to associate nested dictionaries: a list of pastas as one item associated with the food category, for example.

Comment: Yes, pretty much correct.  I have to use a list due to how the API which triggers this code defines the structure.  I also have to define the entire hierarchy in the accessor; the previous version I wrote did use just parent/child (eg a list of pastas as one item associated with the food category), but that breaks if you have multiple cases of same-item-name/different-item-pair parent/child:  eg [people, Smith, Steve, Allen] and [names, S-names, Smith, Steve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This?

```
>>> lst = ['food', 'dinner', 'pasta', 'white sauce', 'fetucci alfredo']
>>> for i in range(len(lst)):
...   print lst[:i+1]
... 
['food']
['food', 'dinner']
['food', 'dinner', 'pasta']
['food', 'dinner', 'pasta', 'white sauce']
['food', 'dinner', 'pasta', 'white sauce', 'fetucci alfredo']
```

So at each "step" of the loop, `lst[:i+1]` is your "current index with all the previous indices" and you can do whatever you wish with it.

For example, you can use it to index into some deeply nested hierarchical dict:

```
d = mydict
for index in lst[:i+1]:
  d = d[index]
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this may do it :)

Comment: You could also use the spellings `for i in range(1, len(lst)+1:` or `for i, _ in enumerate(lst, 1):`, which eliminate the need to do fencepost arithmetic inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks again, this indeed did solve it.  All patched and pushed now.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is like a tree data structure

```
test = ['animal', 'dog', 'golden retriever']
tree = {}
subtree = tree
for x in test:
    subtree = subtree.setdefault(x, {})
```

the `tree` is `{'animal': {'dog': {'golden retriever': {}}}}`

Good luck!